# Perl Handling Malformed Characters

Tags: perl, encoding

I'd like advice about Perl.

I have text files I want to process with Perl. Those text files are encoded in cp932, but for some reasons they may contain malformed characters.

My program is like:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use encoding 'utf-8';

# 'workfile.txt' is supposed to be encoded in cp932
open my $in, "<:encoding(cp932)", "./workfile.txt";

while ( my $line = <$in> ) {

  # my process comes here

  print $line;

}
```

If workfile.txt includes malformed characters, Perl complains:

```
cp932 "\x81" does not map to Unicode at ./my_program.pl line 8, <$in> line 1234.
```

Perl knows if its input contains malformed characters. So I want to rewrite to see if my input is good or bad and act accordingly, say print all good lines (lines that do not contain malformed characters) to output filehandle A, and print lines that do contain malformed characters to output filehandle B.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use encoding 'utf-8';
use English;

# 'workfile.txt' is supposed to be encoded in cp932
open my $in, "<:encoding(cp932)", "./workfile.txt";

open my $output_good, ">:encoding(utf8)", "good.txt";
open my $output_bad,  ">:encoding(utf8)", "bad.txt";

select $output_good;   # in most cases workfile.txt lines are good

while ( my $line = <$in> ) {

  if ( $line contains malformed characters ) {

    select $output_bad;

  }

  print "$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER: $line";

  select $output_good;

}
```

My question is how I can write this "if ($line contains malfoomed characters)" part. How can I check if input is good or bad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `use encoding`. Buggy. Deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use utf8;                             # Source encoded using UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # STD* is UTF-8;
                                      #   UTF-8 is default encoding for open.
use Encode qw( decode );

open my $fh_in,   "<:raw", "workfile.txt"
   or die $!;
open my $fh_good, ">",     "good.txt"
   or die $!;
open my $fh_bad,  ">:raw", "bad.txt"
   or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$fh_in> ) {
   my $decoded_line =
      eval { decode('cp932', $line, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC) };
   if (defined($decoded_line)) {
      print($fh_good "$. $decoded_line");
   } else {
      print($fh_bad  "$. $line");
   }
}
```

Comment: ikegami san, thank you very much! I'll use `eval` to see if there is malformed characters. Arigato!

Comment: I didn't look at what cp932 was when I wrote that. But I see it's a multibyte encoding. That means `my $line = <$fh_in>` might not work properly.

Comment: ikegami, I'm not smart enough to think of situations where `my $line = <$fh_in>` breaks, but I'm happy to report that my program using the eval technique works perfectly detecting all malformed data. Thank you very much! Noted that this might not work in certain situations.

Comment: Problems will happen if 0A can be part of a character other than newline. I don't know if that's possible or not here.

Comment: ikegami, thanks again. Malformed data could contain 0A, but so far so good. I note that reading lines from file handle may break.